# Como ordenar e imprimir una lista en C?

Tags: c, estructuras-de-datos

Mi pregunta es como hago para imprimir la lista de las 10 mejores alumnas(**no alumnos**) primero tendria que hacer un ordenamiento de las notas con un bucle menor a 10? tiene que ser si o si con qsort() ? Como hago para imprimir los nombres de las alumnas (no los numeros de la notas) , aca les dejo las preguntas para que puedan entender mejor mi codigo. **La pregunta que no entiendo es solo la N°2, los otros ya estan echos.**

N1° : Ingresar los datos de los alumnos de un establecimiento consistentes en NOMBRE(string de30 caracteres) ; Sexo (char) ; Y NOTAS de 10 materias codificadas de 0 a 9 (int).El ingreso terminara cuando se ingrese el nombre "FIN".Se sabe que el establecimiento no tiene mas de 1000 Alumnos.

**N2° : IMPRIMIR LA LISTA DE LAS 10 MEJORES ALUMNAS. (ESTE ES EL QUE NO EINTIENDO)**

N°3: Indicar cuantos alumnos hay en el establecimiento cuyo promedio sea mayor o igual que 4 y menor que 7.

N°4: Permitir el ingreso de un nombre y mostrar la totalidad de sus datos, o bien si no pertenece al establecimiento.

**Para ordenar las 10 mejores notas busque y tengo entiendido que se puede hacer con qsort() pero no entiendo como imprimir los nombres de esas notas y no los numeros**

El codigo:

[code]

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 #include<string.h>
 #include<ctype.h>
 #include<ncurses.h>

   #define MAX_ALUMNOS 3


   #define MAX_NOTAS 3

   struct alumno
   {
    char nombre[20];
    char sexo;
    int notas[MAX_NOTAS];
    float promedio_final;
    };

   char nombre_a_buscar[20];

int main()
{
struct alumno alumnos[MAX_ALUMNOS];
int num_alumnos;

for(num_alumnos=0; num_alumnos<MAX_ALUMNOS; num_alumnos++)
{
    printf("Nombre del alumno (para terminar teclee FIN): ");
    scanf("%s",alumnos[num_alumnos].nombre);
    if( strcmp(alumnos[num_alumnos].nombre,"FIN") == 0 )
        break;

    // else ....
    // nota que como el if tiene un break no es necesario el else
    do
    {
        char sexo;
        printf("Sexo: M o F: ");
        scanf("%s",&sexo);
        alumnos[num_alumnos].sexo = toupper(sexo);
    }

    while(alumnos[num_alumnos].sexo != 'M' && alumnos[num_alumnos].sexo !='F');
    float prom = 0.0;
    int sum = 0;

    for (int j=0; j<MAX_NOTAS; j++)
    {
        printf("Ingrese nota #%d: ",j+1);
        scanf("%d",&alumnos[num_alumnos].notas[j]);
        sum += alumnos[num_alumnos].notas[j];

    }
    prom = (float) sum / MAX_NOTAS;
    printf("Promedio de este alumno: %.2f \n", prom);


}

int total = 0;

for (int i=0; i<num_alumnos; i++)
{
    int suma = 0;
    float promedio = 0.0;

    for (int j=0; j<MAX_NOTAS; j++)
        suma += alumnos[i].notas[j];

    promedio = (float) suma / MAX_NOTAS;
    alumnos[i].promedio_final = promedio;

    if (promedio >= 4.0 && promedio < 7.0 )
        total++;
}

printf("Total de alumnos con promedio >= 4 y promedio < 7 = ");
printf("%d \n", total);

do
{
printf("Ingrese un nombre para mostrar datos: ");
scanf("%s", nombre_a_buscar);

bool hay_coincidencia = false;

for(int i=0;i<MAX_ALUMNOS;i++){

    if(strcmp(alumnos[i].nombre, nombre_a_buscar) == 0) {
        hay_coincidencia = true;
        printf("Nombre: %s \nSexo: %c \n", alumnos[i].nombre, alumnos[i].sexo);
        for(int j=0;j<MAX_NOTAS;j++)
            printf("Nota: #%d: %d \n", j+1, alumnos[i].notas[j]);
        printf("Promedio: %.2f \n", alumnos[i].promedio_final);
    }
}
if(!hay_coincidencia)
    printf("El nombre ingresado no se encuentra en la lista\n");
}
while(true);
return 0;
}
```

[/code]

Answer (score 1):

`qsort` es una función de ordenación que tiene la siguiente firma:

```
void qsort (void* base, size_t num, size_t size,
            int (*compar)(const void*,const void*));
```

Donde:

- `base`: puntero al primer elemento a ordenar
- `num`: número de elementos a ordenar
- `size`: tamaño (en bytes) de cada elemento
- `compar`: puntero a función que permita comparar dos elementos

Básicamente lo que tienes que hacer es crear una función que reciba dos elementos de tipo `struct alumno` que sea capaz de indicar cual debe ir delante en la ordenación. Para ello debes calcular el promedio de cada alumno. Yo en este caso crearía una segunda función que me devolviese la suma de las notas (odio repetir código):

```
int suma_notas(struct alumno* alumno)
{
  int total = 0;
  for( int i=0; i<MAX_NOTAS; i++ )
    total += alumno->notas[i];

  return total;
}
```

**nota:** Podría haberlo hecho igual si me devolviese el promedio... pero el promedio es únicamente una división que no aporta nada (si la suma de notas es mayor el promedio será igualmente mayor).

Ahora lo que nos interesa es que queden al principio de la lista los alumnos con mejores promedios. Para ello hay que devolver lo siguiente:

- X<0 si el primer elemento va delante del segundo
- X==0 si ambos elementos son iguales en términos de la comparación
- X>0 si el primer elemento va detrás del segundo

Dicho con números. Nos interesa que se queden arriba los que tienen mejores notas. Si, por ejemplo, tenemos un alumno con una suma = 10 y otro con suma = 11, tendremos que devolver un número >0, luego podemos solucionar el problema con una simple resta: 11-10=1>0, luego basta con restarle al segundo alumno la suma de notas del primero:

```
int OrdenarPorPromedio(const void* alumno1, const void* alumno2)
{
  int suma1 = suma_notas((struct alumno*)alumno1);
  int suma2 = suma_notas((struct alumno*)alumno2);

  return suma2 - suma1;
}
```

Como puedes ver, la parte fea de usar `qsort` es que los parámetros son punteros a void, por lo que para poder acceder a los miembros de `struct alumno` debemos hacer un cast.

Ya tenemos todo lo necesario para ordenar nuestra lista:

```
qsort(alumnos,num_alumnos,sizeof(struct alumno),OrdenarPorPromedio);
```

Después de esto te puedes centrar en los primeros 10 alumnos y ese será el resultado del problema.